# Windows XP Home Edition SP3 WiFi WPA2 not working

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

My netbook OS is Windows XP Home Edition SP3. My wireless network option shows WPA/WPA2 option when I select it, it connects to the router but no internet access. Then I changed my router settings to WEP and configured my netbook and it works fine. I want to use WPA2 security. Please could anyone help to fix this issue?

Comment: router make/model/firmware version?  netbook make/model?   NIC make/model/firmware version?  need more info bro

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your wireless router then open the network status page for your wireless connection (*Control Panel > Network Connections*, double-click your wireless connection). Then open the **Support** tab and click **Repair**. Wait until Windows completes the entire repair process.

If 'repair' does not solve the problem, open the properties dialog for your wireless connection (*Control Panel > Network Connections*, right-click your wireless connection and click **Properties**). Now open the **Wireless Networks** tab. Under **Preferred Networks**, double-click your wireless network. Make sure that the option selected for **Network Authentication** and **Data encryption** match your router settings.

Finally, if none of the above solves the problem, try upgrading the driver for your wireless network adapter.

Comment: While you are at it, Right click on My Computer and select Properties. Once you are in there, go to your Device Manager. Find the wireless card driver and uninstall it. Reboot after the driver is uninstalled. Then let windows reinstall the device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running MAC adress filtering on your wireless router? If so, check the properties on the wireless card in your netbook, and make sure that the network adress value on the Advanced tab is set to the mac adress of your wireless card, and not set to "Not Present". That was the problem I had with me eee pc. I got the correct mac adress for my wireless card by running ipconfig /all at a DOS prompt.